# yarn ios, BUILD FAILED , iOS Simulator deployment target, Skipping duplicate build file, & Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function

Tags: ios

In trying to run yarn ios, I am getting the following error:

```
** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
        PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User]\ Generate\ Specs /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BuildName-faygufgdsrfglcfahsrkkmtauupe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBReactNativeSpec.build/Script-0C35A2F56EF75176BBFC7752C41EE8DC.sh

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

I am getting these errors:

```
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'Flipper-Glog' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.4, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'Flipper-PeerTalk' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'boost-for-react-native' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'YogaKit' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'Flipper-DoubleConversion' from project 'Pods')
```

also getting this error:

```
warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select a development team in the project name editor. (in target 'project name' from project 'project name')
warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Compile Sources build phase: /Users/...../node_modules/react-native/React/FBReactNativeSpec/..../node_modules/react-native/React/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec-generated.mm (in target 'FBReactNativeSpec' from project 'Pods')
warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Copy Headers build phase: /Users/.../node_modules/react-native/React/FBReactNativeSpec/..../node_modules/react-native/React/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec.h (in target 'FBReactNativeSpec' from project 'Pods')

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
        PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User]\ Generate\ Specs /Users/..../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/...-faygufgdsrfglcfahsrkkmtauupe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBReactNativeSpec.build/Script-0C35A2F56EF75176BBFC7752C41EE8DC.sh
(1 failure)
```

I ran "yarn start". I installed XCode. I did a

```
sudo gem install cocoapods 
pod install
```

any ideas? Thnx

Comment: I have the same issue after upgrading react native to 0.64, any clue on what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

it is necessary to install XCode first b4  doing all of these steps like:

```
npx react-native init TikTok
yarn start 
yarn ios
```

I did not have XCode installed & tried to install it after going thru all these steps & got all the errors listed above.

I eventually started all over & just ran

```
npx react-native init TikTok
yarn start 
yarn ios
```

in another folder & it solved the problem